# Implementing rand function

Tags: php, function

I have the following section of code.  Is there anyway that I can use the php `rand()` function to randomly display items within the foreach?.  I have tried google but I am getting confused how to implement it into this situation.

```
<?php
$dir = 'catalog/view/theme/default/gallery/';?>
<div id="Box">
<div id="slideShow">
<ul>
<?php foreach(glob($dir.'*.jpg') as $file) : ?>
<li><img width="370" height="480" alt="" src="<?=$file?>"/></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't want the files in the order that the glob() returns them to you in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to display all of the images but in a random order, you could try something like this:

```
<?php
    $files = glob($dir . "*.jpg");
    shuffle($files);
    foreach($files as $file):
?>
<li><img width="370" height="480" alt="" src="<?= $file ?>" /></li>
<?php
    endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used `rand()` in my `SELECT` query before using `foreach` like `order by rand()` it too worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the files into an array and use array_rand

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php